# c# autocad dllimport by autocad version

Tags: c#, dllimport, autocad

i have been using the the program from "Detecting entities under cursor while selection is running" By Philippe Leefsma located here[1](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2014/02/detecting-entities-under-cursor-while-selection-is-running.html). it worked in ACAD2014 however now we are using ACAD2016. it will not work because of the DLLImport of acdb19.dll and autocad2016 needs acdb20.dll. Is there a way to make the program load eighter dll version? i tried using netload and assembly.loadfrom and neither worked.

[Point Monitor callback](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2014/02/detecting-entities-under-cursor-while-selection-is-running.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL import is set at compile time so the best bet is to compile two versions for each release of AutoCAD.

Once the project is compiled, you could set up an autoloader by creating an application.bundle folder. this folder can be placed in c:\programdata\Autodesk\applicationPlugins. In the application.bundle folder, create a subfolder called Application and place the compiled .DLL file in there.
[image: application.bundle folder contents]

The loader is controlled with an XML file which should be named PackageContents.xml. Here's some example code for the xml file:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationPackage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     Name="My AutoCAD App"
     Description="Does something in AutoCAD"
     Icon="./Application/MyIcon.ico"
     Author="Paul Nelson">
 <CompanyDetails Name="Paul Nelson"
     Url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
     Email="myemail@email.com">
 </CompanyDetails>
 <Components>
  <!-- define the min and max versions of AutoCA in the next line -->
  <RuntimeRequirements OS="Win64" Platform="AutoCAD" SeriesMin="R19.0" SeriesMax="R22.0" />
  <ComponentEntry
   ModuleName=".\Application\MyApp.dll"
   LoadOnAutoCADStartup="true"
   LoadOnCommandInvocation="false"
   AppDescription="This is assembly MyApp."
   AppName="My AutoCAD App"
   AppType=".NET">

   <Commands GroupName="My Apps">
    <Command Local="MYAPP" Global="MYAPP" />
   </Commands>

  </ComponentEntry>
 </Components>
</ApplicationPackage>
```

One last tip - make sure the .dll filename does not contain spaces.

Comment: thanks for the info. we use the application.bundle as a means of auto-updating in-house dll files. did not occur to me to do the version check in there.